# About ClassLoader, what happen if we didn't delegate to the parent class loader?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

A ClassLoader should delegate the loading process to it's parent first. This is some docs says.

So, what happen if we don't follow this pattern. that is:

We override loadClass, and in it's implementation, we directly call:

```
defineClass(...)  // get Class objet for a given byte array
resoveClass(...)  // link class to vm
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that? Can you give an example in code which would call such a classloader? How would you -for example- load java.lang.String?

Comment: what happens is, that your custom classloader is only able to load those classes which you fed it with - so what usually should happen is, that on trying to execute your programm, your class to load will report an error as core classes could not be found, unless you loaded them manually. This is what SirRichie has already mentioned in short. Without delegation, you need to load all needed classes manually by that classloader.

Comment: @RomanVottner what's the "core class"? is those in rt.jar? because our classloader is a subclass of the root classloader we can "see" all those core class. is this right?

Comment: @lovespring core-classes are mainly classes in rt.jar but also classes your programm will depend on will be required to be loaded by you manually - so every dependent class has to be loaded by your class-loader. Not sure why you need to do this as delegation (with parenting) classloaders is more convenient but yet powerful enough. Unless you want to create your own version of f.e. java.lang classes, I don't see a necessity of going your route

Comment: @RomanVottner just for learning. I don't really use classloader in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat's Web Application Classloader is an example of a Classloader that does not (always) delegate the loading process to its parent first (as per Servlet Specification). The [classloader-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) article explains this and also gives insight in what (not) to do. If you want to know how it works in practice, you can view the source code of [WebappClassLoader](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader.java).

On a side node, creating a [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) without passing on `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` as parent classloader in the constructor can give surprising results if the current Thread was started with a custom Classloader. The URLClassLoader will only know the classes from the System Classloader and the classes in the URLs provided, but not the classes from the custom Classloader.